# Проблемы с методом Split() | C#

Tags: c#, list, split

У меня есть текст, мне нужно разделить его по предложениям, то есть по точкам `Split('.')` и закинуть в `List<>`. Все в принципе прекрасно, но в последнем предложении тоже есть точка и в лист так же попадает все что идет после нее, то есть пустота. Вот как мне сказать, что если там конец, то нужно здесь становиться?

Answer (score 4):

```
var str = "1.2.3.";
var strs = str.Split('.', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Ответ хороший, но если в предложении будет "..." то оно уберет и эти пустоты. А вопрос в том подходит ли это автору вопроса т.к. он говорил только за последнюю точку. С меня все равно плюс

Answer (score 0):

```
var lines = "привет. Меня зовут Dazzy. Меня мучает вопрос на StackOverflow."
                .Split('.').ToList();

if (lines.Last() == "") {
    lines.RemoveAt(lines.Count -1);
}
```

Comment: В моем случае не ```var```, а ```string[]``` и здесь вылезает ошибка, что у ```string[]``` нет метода RemoveAt

Comment: там не может быть `string[]` потому что у меня в коде написано  `.ToList()`. Скопируй код дословно и протестируй. Все работает.

Comment: `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` поэффективне будет

Comment: @aepot согласен. И код красивее. Только есть одно "но" - но если в предложении будет "..." то оно уберет и эти пустоты. А вопрос в том подходит ли это автору вопроса т.к. он говорил только за последнюю точку/пустоту. Т.е. мой ответ был с учетом этого.

Comment: А если представить что он потом хочет соединять назад все через точку после обработки ячеек - то вместо "..." получит "."  :)